# Fade btw two elements jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

i want to add a fade between this elements in my code

some help?

```
$("#example p:first").css("display", "block");

jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
    if(!$(this).children("p:last-child").is(":visible")){
        $(this).children("p:visible")
            .css("display", "none")
            .next("p").css("display", "block");
    }

}

window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#example").timer();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#example p').each(function(index) {

 $(this).delay((index+1)*1000).fadeIn(500);

});
```

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/b0we0g3h/1/**

You don't need setInterval, in this case, you can use delay(): https://api.jquery.com/delay/

P.S. If you want that first p tag appears without delay, use just index, not index+1.